# Java Tomcat 8.5 / Spring 4 Removes Multiple Spacing from URL

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, whitespace, spacing

I'm working on an existing Spring 4 application which sits in a Tomcat (I believe 8.5) container.

The Problem:

When the String controller receives its parameters, any multiple spacing within the URL is removed, but I want it to be included

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

When this is submitted with `/getData/Joe%20Bloggs/`, the name variable will be 'Joe Bloggs'

But when submitted with `/getData/Joe%20%20%20Bloggs/`, the variable remains 'Joe Bloggs'. The multiple spaces are ignored.

---

Any idea where this functionality is being defined, and whether this is being done by the Tomcat container or the Spring framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your requestmapping as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData/{name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: I actually tried this, but it didn't seem to change anything, do you know what the '.+' doing? The argument variable still had its spaces removed further up the stack trace in eclipse debug

Comment: '.+' is a regex. It will match any character in the URL. I tried it with glassfish and spring 5. It is working fine there with or without the regex.